# Grafana access not working in Kube Prometheus Stack 46.4.1

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, kube-prometheus-stack

I'm trying to access grafana but I'm not able to access with **admin/my_password**, where **my_password** is the value set in my custom_values.yaml file. I get username/password doesn't exist error. I can confirm the password value has been set with my_password with the following command:

```
kubectl get secret --namespace monitoring prometheus-grafana -o jsonpath="{.data.admin-password}" | base64 --decode ; echo
```

Here is how I'm setting the value in my custom_values.xml file

```
adminPassword: "my_password"
```

I would really appreciate any help in this.